# Android sign apk file

Tags: android, apk, sign

I use this tutorial for sign my apk [link](http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/keytool/)

but I have stopped on the step **Sign your application**.

There is

```
./sign-mac-example.sh ../DialANumber/deploy/DialANumber.apk
Enter passphrase:
```

command

this not an internal or external program as I see in command line.

I use windows.

I have create all folder in workspce there are:

- androidkeys (where I store my key my-release-key.keystore)
- deploy (where I have export my apk file)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Eclipse for signing Android Apps.

Therefore you have to install Android SDK and plugin for Eclipse. Create a project - When you're done, rghtclick on your Project and click export.

The wizard allows you to create a new keystore or use an existing one to sign your app.

I  tried signing apps with console using Ubuntu, but it was hard - With Eclipse it's very easy  and the export wizard creates the .apk

Answer (score 3):

I can see this section a bit higher in the tutorial than the place you cite:

> Write a short script to make your life easier Just to make the life
>   easier I wrote a short script which can be used each time to sign your
>   Android APK file. You can download it below and place it in the same
>   directory you placed the keystore at (see point 2).

Here the guy defines the script he calls with `./sign-mac-example.sh`. However, regretfully this script is meat to work on linux and mac, not windows.

Nevermind the only line that is really crucial in this script is this:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore my-release-key.keystore "$1" alias_name
```

And you can use it in Windows also, just replace "$1" with `../DialANumber/deploy/DialANumber.apk`.

I actually can not justify why the guy resorted to additional script here.